# Integral of Bessel functions multiply Legendre polynomials.

Tags: bessel-functions, legendre-polynomials

Given $x_{i}$ is a fixed point in [-L,L], $l_{0}$ and $L$ is also positive constant.
$|x_{i}-y|$ represent absolute value of $(x_{i}-y)$. define $z=\frac{|x_{i}-y|}{l_{o}}$.

$\mathbf{H_{\alpha}}$ is Struve function. $Y_{\alpha}$ is Bessel
function of the second kind. $P_{n}$ is Legendre polynomials.

My question is how to do the following integral?

$$\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}(\frac{\mathbf{H}_{1}(z)}{z}-\frac{2}{\pi z^{2}}-\frac{Y_{0}(z)+Y_{2}(z)}{2})P_{j}(\frac{2y}{L})dy$$

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Numerically, I think. The absolute value in the definition of $z$ makes this integral a nightmare.

Comment: okay, is that possible to use symmetrical integral limit to remove absolute value?  And it is said in the literature that this integral has an analytical solution. But I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: Can you reference the aforementioned literature?

Comment: here is the paper: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.038102